# Drawing multilingual text using PIL (Part II)

Tags: python-imaging-library, python-3.3

This is a (hopefully) simple follow-up to the question someone previously asked.

I'm on Windows 7 64-bit, running Python 3.3 and Pillow.

The script below outputs two versions of a Hindi word to separate image files, but it frequently transposes the characters. How do I ensure that the characters printed to a jpg/png match the order of the same characters in text?

Thank you,
C

#

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw
import string, random
#Hindi words: विश्वसनीय, असरदार, उपयुक्त, सीढ़ी, पेंसिल, डिब्बा
# -----------------------------------
# write text to an image
# ----------------------------------
img=Image.new("RGB", [400, 400])
font = ImageFont.truetype("mangal.ttf", 76)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw.text((20, 10),"विश्वसनीय",(255,255,255),font=font)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
img.save("a_test.jpg")
# -----------------------------------
# write text to an image2
# ----------------------------------
image=Image.new("RGB",[400,400])
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
a=u"विश्वसनीय"
font=ImageFont.truetype("mangal.ttf", 76)
draw.text((50, 50), a, font=font)
image.save("a_test2.png")
##########################################
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that your problem is that you are drawing a 9 character string in a 76 point in a 400x400 pixel image starting at 50, 50 - so it is either wrapping or clipping and getting messed up - try changing your point size to 32 or your image to 800x800.

*(IIRC 76 points is approximately 100 pixel per character.)*